# Codeigniter Post data using AngularJS - save in database

Tags: json, angularjs, codeigniter, controller

I am using Codeigniter and AngularJS.

Can someone help me?
I would like to save $scope.ListTabel to the database. It is possible for "FOR" to pass in the codeigniter controller - to be executed on the server and not in javascript?
Thanks a lot!

```
$scope.ListaTabel = [];

$scope.adauga_in_tabel = function () {
    var camp = {};
    camp.tbl_date = new Date();
    camp.tbl_consumator = ServGlob.data.consumator;
    camp.tbl_produs = ServGlob.data.produs;
    camp.tbl_cantitate = ServGlob.data.cantitate;
    camp.tbl_pret = ServGlob.data.pret;
    $scope.ListaTabel.push(camp);
}

$scope.salveaza = function(){
  for(var i = 0; i < $scope.ListaTabel.length; i++){
      var item = $scope.ListaTabel[i];
      $scope.items = {date: item.tbl_date, consumator: item.tbl_consumator, produs: item.tbl_produs, pret: item.tbl_pret};
      $http.post('<?php echo base_url()."consum/add_consum";?>', $scope.items);
  }
  //$scope.ListaTabel = null;
  //$scope.items = null;
}


Codeigniter Controller

public function add_consum()
{
    $request= json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), TRUE);
    $data=$this->Consum_model->insert_consum($request);
    //$this->session->set_flashdata('message', 'Datele au fost salvate cu succes...');
}

Codeigniter Model

public function insert_consum($request)
 {
    //$val = array(
    //     'date' => $request['date'],
    //       'consumator' => $request['consumator'],
    //       'produs' => $request['produs'],
    //       'pret' => $request['pret']
    // );
   $insert=$this->db->insert('consum',$request);
   return $insert;
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think the best solution would be to store alle data in an array and after that send it to the server

something like the following should work

Your JS Controller function

```
$scope.salveaza = function()
{

    let arrItems = [];
    for(var i = 0; i < $scope.ListaTabel.length; i++)
    {
        var item = $scope.ListaTabel[i];
        let itemToPost = {date: item.tbl_date, consumator: item.tbl_consumator, produs: item.tbl_produs, pret: item.tbl_pret};

        arrItems.push(itemToPost);
    }
    $http.post('<?php echo base_url()."consum/add_consum";?>', arrItems).then(function(result){
        //do whatever you want
    });
}
```

and your controller function

```
public function add_consum()
{
    $request= json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'));

    foreach($request as $arrItem)
    {
        $this->Consum_model->insert_consum($arrItem);
    }
    //$this->session->set_flashdata('message', 'Datele au fost salvate cu succes...');
}
```

Comment: thanks.

I tried. I understand the idea but I can't get it to work. I don't know if it sends to the controller or receives the controller

Comment: its a bit hard with _can't get it to work_ check your request array and edit your question with the output, or maybe you have a javascript error ?

Comment: It works perfectly with a slight change in the controller
foreach($request as $key=>$value)
        {
            $this->Consum_model->insert_consum($value);
        }
Thanks a lot!